# Unsupported type when using group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, knitr, attr

I have a problem when trying to knit the markdown. When I run the following code:

```
matchlist <- data.frame(LIST) %>%
             group_by(school) %>%
             filter(match_score == min(match_score))
```

I get the following error:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
>       Column `testscore` is of unsupported type NULL
>       Calls:  ... group_by.data.frame -> 
>       grouped_df -> grouped_df_impl -> .Call

"testscore" is the other column in the dataframe, LIST,  and this error does not occur when I just run this chunk. Another thing I notice is that when I run the above code, I get a bunch of "attr" attached on the matchlist and that the class of matchlist is

```
> class(matchlist)
  [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

instead of just the "data.frame".

The simplified structure of "LIST" are:

```
code    school    testscore    match_score
   1       aaa          aaa              0
   1       aaa          aba          0.211
   1       aaa          bba          0.544
   2       bbb          bvv          0.888
   2       bbb          bbd          0.015
   3       ccc          sss          0.899
   ...     ...          ...            ...
```

I made pairs for each of the school by using testscore and did the fuzzy matching (the matching score is the last column). I am trying to choose the best score(minimal) for each of the school, so I grouped them by the school name and tried to make matchlist.

I would appreciate if you could help me solve this issue.

---

This is the dput outcome.

```
> dput(droplevels(head(LIST, 4)))
structure(list(code = c(102, 102, 102, 104), school = c("UNIVERSITY OF AAA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF AAA", "UNIVERSITY OF AAA", 
"BBB COLLEGE"), testscore = c("UNIVERSITY OF AAA", 
"UNIVERSITY OF SOUTH AAA", "AAA COLLEGE", 
"UNIVERSITY OF AAA SCHOOL"), match_score = c(0.0797101449275361, 
0.194990021076978, 0.366802437561176, 0.46046176046176)), .Names = c("code", 
"school", "testscore", "match_score"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Comment: check the `str(data.frame(LIST)` before doing the `group_by` step

Comment: Thanks for your comments. str(data.frame(LIST)) returns data.frame': 2105 obs. of 4 variables: $ code : num ... $ school : chr ... $ testscore : chr ... $ match_score: num ... LIST does not have any attr. When trying group_by, it will produce error all of a sudden.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example by providing the first few cases of `LIST` .

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Comment: Your code works on the example data you provided

Comment: Yes, it works fine when just running the chunk or running them on the console. The error occurs only when trying to knit.

Comment: If an error happens only when you knit, it generally means that the code in your Rmarkdown file doesn't actually capture all the steps you used to get to your current state in the current session. If you restart your R session (you will lose the current state of your workspace) and try running through all your code again, you should be able to spot the issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have restarted a couple of times, but that does not solve the error. In the earlier part of the code, I got the following message: 
Warning message:
In function_list[[k]](value) 
Does this warning matter? Going chunk by chunk is totally fine and this warning does not seem to cause other errors,  but this is the only warning I get before the knitting error.

Comment: No idea, but when stuck like that, I try to eliminate all possible conflicts... maybe do not call it LIST, as it might be a reserved word?  also make sure all libraries are included in the markdown.. When I tried you example it passed my knitr. So maybe reduce your markdown file to the strict minimum so that you can reproduce your issue with it and share the markdown code to see if we can reproduce it. Also try to override the type of your column as it might be of an unexpected class because of a previous operation and do an unclass if in doubt

Comment: Restart R and go through the document one chunk at a time. See where the structure of the data changes to what you don't expect. It goes without saying that understanding the code 100% will reap benefits down the line.